# Help passing GET data to a php file in the same location as my Java applet

Tags: java, php

I have a java applet trying to pass some GET data to a php file in the same directory as my applet. When I start a url connection to the file.php and pass the data, I don't get anything, however when I append the full URL in front of the PHP file, it works.

Here's what I have:

```
URL sp = new URL ("file.php?data1=" + data1 + "&data2=" + data2 + "&data3=" + data3);
BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sp.openStream()));
```

But, the data only gets passed if i add my full http://www.website.com/ url in front of file.php

EDIT:
    It works now, with a URL test = new URL(getCodeBase(), "form.php");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given documents located:
 - http://www.website.com/docs/applet.html (document base)
 - http://www.website.com/forms/form.php (target form)

server (http://www.website.com/)

- docs

  - applet.html
- forms

  - form.php

An URL to `form.php` can be created using either of..

```
// relative URL
URL relative = new URL(getDocumentBase(), "../forms/form.php");
// absolute URL
URL absolute = new URL(getDocumentBase(), "/forms/form.php");
```

Comment: Thanks, it actually worked fine again when I tried, with 
  getCodeBase(), "form.php"...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Applet's getCodeBase?](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase%28%29)

As per document

```
public URL getCodeBase()
   Gets the base URL. This is the URL of the directory which contains this applet.
  Returns:
    the base URL of the directory which contains this applet.
```